# How to only get one level deep with EntityFramework 5 on navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, automapper

Right now I have proxy creation disabled:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I have a data model like so (removed non-relevant fields):

```
public partial class Video
{    
    public int VideoID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Videos = new HashSet<Video>();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Unit of Work and Repository patterns to load my data like so,

Get all video's, including the user object:

```
var videos = videoService
                .Include(v => v.User)
                .Get()
```

I am using automapper to map from data model to domain model (hence the UI namespace in the screenshot below).  When I inspect the video enumeration I get back, and look at the first item in the enumeration, I go to check the user object:

[image]

What I **expect** here is the VideoModel to be filled with data(ok), with only it's single UserModel entity to be filled with data(ok), and all collections in the UserModel to be empty(this is broke).  As you can see in the second red box above, the Videos collection is populated with 6 videos.  And on those video's, the user's are filled in.  So this basically creates a very large object graph.

**1) Can I make it so when using an include that it ONLY goes 1 level deep (IE doesn't fill in Video.User.Videos)?



2) Why doesn't ProxyCreationEnabled = false take care of this?  Am I expecting too much?**

p.s. I want to avoid creating a customer mapper for this with automapper.
p.p.s. I am doing db first, not model first

Comment: I assume what you want is similar to the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.90).aspx) function in Entity Framework? For older versions, this was required to populate data in foreign keyed tables. (also just realized you might be using it already).

Comment: Yes, I am using it that way.  I don't understand why it is loading the parent.child.children entities when I try to only include the parent.child entity.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Yes, my team and I wrote a custom tool similar to AutoMapper that only goes as deep as we need it.  It's based on AutoMapper as well.  Unfortunately we use it on client projects so I cannot share much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

By default, EntityFramework uses lazy loading for virtual properties (such as `User` and `Videos` in your example). If you want these properties to be filled prior to them actually being accessed, you can use `Include()` or, to go another level deep, an `Include()` with a nested `Select()`.

This default behavior, however, relies on the creation of a proxy class, which you have apparently turned off.

Not knowing all the things you're trying to do, this may not work, but it seems like you would get the behavior you wanted by simply removing `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` and using `Include()` as you have.

Also, viewing properties in the debugger may be misleading because you are in fact accessing the property when you try to view it in the debugger (which could cause the lazy loaded entity or collection to be filled right then, making you think it had been eagerly loaded).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I verified that proxy creation was disabled when the Repo was instanced.  It also serializes it when converting to Json, so it's not caused by me inspecting it is what I am seeing so far.